# proving whether a quantity is a tensor or not

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

For example prove that $A^{ij}_j$ transforms like a rank  2 tensor or prove that $A^{ii}_j$ is not a tensor. I did find a couple of answers already, but they were not too helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to know details about $A$ in order to determine its transformation properties.  However, this is a question which looks like it would be more at home on [math SE](http://www.math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this type of problem, one is given an object, call it $T$, as a function of one or more tensors, call them $A$, $B$, ..., i.e.,
$$T=f(A,B,...)$$
for some function $f$.

Since $A$, $B$, etc. are tensors, they transform under a change in basis according to the tensor transformation rules.  So for example, denoting $A'$ as the components of $A$ in the new basis, $A'$ will be $A$ multiplied by zero or more instances of $R$ and/or $R^{-1}$, where $R$ is the matrix that effects the change in basis. (On a Euclidean space, $R$ will be an orthogonal matrix which represents a rotation, while on a Minkowski space, $R$ will represent a Lorentz transformation.)

In the new basis, the components of $T$ are changed to
$$T'=f(A',B',...)\ \ .$$
An object is a tensor if and only if it transforms according to the tensor transformation rules.  So $T$ is a tensor if and only if
$$T'=[f(A,B,...)]'\ \ ,$$
where as with the case of $A'$, the prime on the RHS denotes multiplying by zero or more instances of $R$ and/or $R^{-1}$ according to the tensor transformation rules.  I.e., $T$ is a tensor if and only if
$$f(A',B',...)=[f(A,B,...)]'\ \ .$$
So to prove that $T$ is a tensor, you need to prove that that equation always holds.  Or to prove that $T$ is not a tensor, you need to prove that there exist $A$, $B$,... and $R$ such that that equation does not hold.

For example, to prove that $A^{ij}_{j}$ is a tensor (it's actually a rank 1 tensor, not a rank 2 tensor), you need to show that
$$A^{i'j'}_{j'}=A^{ij}_{j}(R^{-1})^{i'}_{i}$$
where
$$A^{i'k'}_{j'}=A^{ik}_{j}(R^{-1})^{i'}_{i}(R^{-1})^{k'}_{k}R^{j}_{j'}\ \ .$$
In other words, you need to show that
$$A^{ik}_{j}(R^{-1})^{i'}_{i}(R^{-1})^{j'}_{k}R^{j}_{j'}=A^{ij}_{j}(R^{-1})^{i'}_{i}\ \ ,$$
which is easy to show because $R^{-1}R=I$.

As the other example, to prove that $A^{ii}_{j}$ is not a tensor, you need to show that the equation
$$A^{i'i'}_{j'}=A^{ii}_{j}R^{j}_{j'}$$
does not hold in general.